# Updating SharePoint Filters in Specific Views

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, filter

I created and saved a view within SharePoint that had filters applied on a specific column. I now want to add additional values into the filtered view, however it appears to still only show the entries that satisfy the original filtered criteria.

Do I have to create a new view to update my filter criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

**Modern experience**:

1. Go to SharePoint list (list view)
2. Apply required filter by selecting column header and "Filter by" option:

   [image]
3. Once you make this small change, you will the * added next to view name (Say "All Items*").
4. Click on switch view options drop down (where "All Items" is shown) and select "Save view as" option:

   [image]
5. Click "Save" button shown on "Save as" pop up - save list view with same name without changing anything:

   [image]

---

**Classic experience**:

1. Go to SharePoint list (list view)
2. Click on switch view options drop down (where "All Items" is shown) and select "Edit current view" option:

   [image]
3. It will open list view settings in new classic experience page. Scroll down to "Filter" section and add filters as per your requirements:

   [image]
4. Click "OK" at the bottom of list view settings page to save the changes.